# Astro: Redirect is not updating the window's location in the address bar

Tags: astrojs

I'm trying to create a login form using Astro similar to what's shown in [Astro's docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/recipes/build-forms/).
However, though the redirect updates the UI, although it doesn't fully render, but the URL in the address bar doesn't change, and so a refresh goes back to the login page.

To narrow it down to the absolute minimal code, this **does** redirect, the URL is updated, and everything in the new page looks correct:

```
---
return Astro.redirect('/home');
if (Astro.request.method === "POST") {
}
---
```

But this does not update the location, and also doesn't apply any styles in the `<style>` block:

```
---
if (Astro.request.method === "POST") {
   return Astro.redirect('/home');
}
---
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you sure you have `<form method="POST">`? you'll need to post more code, perhaps do a minimal example on stackblitz via https://astro.new ? one moe idea: are you using Astro's "View Transitions"? if so, try disabling them...